# Cached jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been developing a number of JS heavy sites recently, whilst I favour the majority of the time using pure JS, jQuery without doubt has its uses and I'm relying on it now mainly for quick event binding / bubbling. My question here is about using jQuery cached objects and how best to use them.

I've found myself doing something along these lines in the majority of my js scripts.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

var doc = jQuery(document), // Root jQ object
    html = doc.children('html'), // Mainly to check modernizr classes
    container = html.find('.container'); // Base content container

/** module 1 **/
(function($, w, undefined) {

    container.on('click', 'button', function(e) {
        ...
    });

})(jQuery, window);

/** module 2 **/
(function($, w, undefined) {

    container.on('click', 'a.module', function(e) {
        // Occasionally creating further jQ objects in contextual situations
        var self = $(this);

        // Or is this better
        var clicked = container.find(this);
    });

})(jQuery, window);
```

As you can see I only ever have one high level jQuery object that I use to traverse the DOM with, whilst occasionally creating new jQuery objects where the context requires it. I toyed with the idea of using a plugin `jQuery.single` though I didn't really feel it was necessary.

Is this actually doing me any favours, I feel that it is better as I'm only creating the fewest number of jQuery objects possible without using jQuery single (see second module code), though I can't be sure. I'm hoping that someone here will be able to shed some light on whether this is viable or should I just stick with my previous methods where I would create jQuery objects within each of my individual closures?

**Example of my previous methods**

```
/** module 1 **/
(function($, w, undefined) {

    var container = $('.container');

    container.on('click', 'button', function(e) {
        ...
    });

})(jQuery, window);

/** module 2 **/
(function($, w, undefined) {

    var container = $('.container');

    container.on('click', 'a.module', function(e) {
        // Occasionally creating further jQ objects in contextual situations
        var self = $(this);
    });

    // Usually if I needed anything further outside the container
    // If create further objects
    var header = $('header');

})(jQuery, window);
```

Comment: The answer is: profile it. I doubt the object-instantiation part is significant; all the computational complexity will come from what you're doing with it. IOW, you're much better off optimizing your selectors/traversal/manipulation methods than worrying about the `$()` part. But to track down what exactly is using up time, there are no shortcuts: profile it. For that matter, I wouldn't even do that until there's something you actually need to speed up. If this is pre-emptive performance optimization, then... stop doing that. Makes your code brittle and probably doesn't help perf anyway.

Comment: Could you give a clear example (two separate codes) of two options you are talking about? Cause I'm a bit lost.

Comment: @freakish added a quick example

Comment: @AdamKG thanks for that, I have been profiling to some extent, the real issue I have is reading a lot of documentation from other developers stating fewer jQuery objects generally = faster. I agree that it does depend what I do with it, however there must be something to backup these other peoples claims.

Comment: @DavidBarker Right, thanks. Well, that's a general rule: fewer objects = better. Especially in this context: you are reusing an object in different parts of code. I think it should be natural to cache it instead of duplicating it. There are other advantages, for example it would be easier to make changes to such code. But to be honest I doubt you'll see any difference. After all there are more important things that eat performance (operations on DOM mostly).